# How to hide or encrypt the video url in FlowPlayer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, streaming, video-streaming, flowplayer

I am using FlowPlayer with ASP.NET MVC and C#. I am trying to hide the URL that is getting displayed in the browser page source in the object element in one of the param elements. The secure streaming plugin page only explains how to achieve security using Wowza Media Server. Can someone explain how do I just hide or encrypt the video URL and the file name that is getting displayed in the page source just by using C# or jQuery with or without the secure streaming plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an Action Method which takes the encrypted video name as the parameter. I decrypted that to the actual video name and redirected to the Media Server inside the Action Method by using return Redirect(URL). In that way the page source displays the URL to my Action Method instead of the Media Server URL. I made the name and parameter of the Action Method less obvious to anybody who views that in the page source.

After, I also added another parameter for a token which is valid for only 24 hours so that anybody with the knowledge of MVC routing cannot recreate the URL by pasting it in the browser directly.

So this was my solution.